# How can I get information about Spotify audio stream

Tags: html, audio, spotify, html5-audio

I want to get information (most important the currently buffered time) about the currently playing music in the Spotify web player.
I can't find any `<audio>` tag in the HTML and through the Spotify Web API, the required information can't be obtained.

Is there any option to access information like the buffer, as it could be done with an `<audio>` tag?

Comment: have a look [here](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-information-about-the-users-current-playback/)

Comment: Thank you, I have searched the API documentation already, but I think there is no possibility to read the buffer